# MongoDB search with wider key

Tags: python, mongodb

Not really sure if mongo is the best solution here or if this is even possible:

I have a document:

```
{
  u'action': [
    {
       u'url': u'http://foo.com',
       u'payload': {
         u'action': u'EndCall'
       }, 
       u'timer': 0
    },
    {
       u'url': u'http://foo.com', 
       u'payload': {
         u'action': u'EndCall'
       },
       u'timer': 0
    }
  ],
  u'pattern': {u'c': 3, u'b': 2, u'd': 4}
}
```

Its effectivly a key/value pair where pattern is the key and action is the value,

Now say I want to retrive this value/document when I search with a string that contains the pattern as well as some other values (which are unknown and irrelevent)

for example my search string that should match above is:

```
query = {"a": 1, "b" : 2, "c" : 3, "d" : 4, "e" : 5 }
```

So the middle part of this matches the pattern value but I can't know which values I can remove to get the exact match (eg a & e)

The app is written in Python as I'm currently trying this in Mongo but happy to explore any other solution.

Comment: What do all the "u"'s in your document represent?

Comment: @MikeBrant, "u" is a Python language literal for unicode strings

Comment: I think you are looking for a $subset operator? There is an improvement request in JIRA to add this operator.  Please feel free to track, up vote, or comment on this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-974

Answer (score 0):

About the only way I can think to do what you are looking to do it to make the query a series of OR options like this:

```
db.foo.find( { $or : [ { "a" : 1 } , { "b" : 2 }, { "c" : 3 }, { "d" : 4 }, { "e" : 5 } ] } )
```

This should work since it seems you are in essence looking for any of these values in any part of the "pattern" node.

Comment: but that would match if ANY one of the values was matched right? so if the string had {"b" : 2, "c" : "dog"} that would still be returned?

Comment: @SamMachin Yes that is correct.  But your example was a bit arbitrary in that you "pattern" node matched the inner part of your search query.  Is there any other logic that need to be applied like it needs to match 3 consecutive parts of the search query or something like that?

Comment: yeah sorry I was a bit vague, the query needs to contain all the values in the key and may contain additional ones. Thanks though.

Comment: @SamMachin Well if your search string isn't going to change dynamically, you could certainly build up a more complex `$or` statement of the different possible combinations, but my guess is that this will not help you.  Really what you are looking to do is kind of an inverse of a typical find operation where you are really trying to "find" a value in your search string, based on the substrings in the document object. Sounds like you might need to reconsider the data structure in order to do what you want.

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought its turning the whole query model on its head, unfortunately not practical to build up the or string as the query string could be huge. Thanks for your help anyway